# Best way to create Android tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I have to create tab Navigation with 3 buttons with one using a MapActivity.
I figured out 3 ways to do it:
 - Using ActionBar
 - Using TabActivity
 - Using FragmentTabHost

I couldn't find which is the best. May someone help me ?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Backward Compatible UI training](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html) goes specifically into how you should build tabs that work across all devices.

Note that you should 100% be using the Google Maps API V2 (which uses [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment)s) rather than the deprecated MapActivity that exists in V1.